# Laravel retrieve only the email address column in database for users table

Tags: php, laravel, collections, orm

Hi I had code that stated

```
    $users = User::all();
```

But I only want the email addresses of the users in a collection. So I tried:

```
    $users = User::select('id', 'email')->first();
```

This does not work as I want. When I do a var_dump I only want to see the users email addresses. Any tips?

UPDATE: I inserted my blade code as well. I use a Vue component that has a dropdown and I filter the data in the Vue method and insert the filtered data under userEmail:

The component:

```
    <commands-component
                :entity-config="commandConfig(command.id, command.signature, command.hasUser, command.title, command.groupID, command.groupName)">
                <input style="margin-right:10px;margin-bottom:10px;" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" v-bind:value="command.title" v-on:click='disableEmailText(command.hasUser)'>
        </commands-component>
```

The Vue:

```
    var systemadmin = new Vue({
    el: "#sysadmin",
    data: function() {
        return {
          users: <?php echo $users ?>,
          userData: [],
          commands: <?php echo $commands ?>,
        }
    },

    methods: {
      commandConfig: function(ident, signature, hasUser, title, groupId, groupName){
        var that =  this;
        var commandsGetUsers = [];


        commandsGetUsers  = _.map(that.users, function(value) {
            var newValue = {};
            newValue.value = value.id;
            newValue.text = value.email;
            return newValue;
        });

        return {
          id: { text: 'commandModal' + ident, id: null },
          modalTitle: title,
          buttons: [
              {
                  buttonTitle: 'Run Command',
                  buttonClass: 'btn btn-success pull-right',
                  submitUrl: {
                      url: '/admin/artisan/commands/run',

                  },
              }
          ],
          attributes: [
            {name: "message", displayName: "Are you sure you want to proceed with the command?", type: "action-text",  col: "12" },
            {name: "signature", displayName: "Command Signature", type:'text', col:"6"},
            {name: "userEmail", displayName: "Users", type: 'select', options: commandsGetUsers, col:'6'}
          ],
          data: {
              signature:signature,
              hasUser:hasUser
          }
        };



      },
```

Comment: [laravel Collections's function only on Elequent ORM result always return empty collection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47256777/6521116)

Comment: email of all users or single user ? Can you elaborate it ?

Comment: All users email addresses :)

Comment: Use pluck `$users = User::pluck('email')->toArray();`
it retrives all the users emails as an array.

Comment: @Rits it gives me error on my blade template then - Array to string conversion. I am using the user emails to populate in a dropdown

Comment: it gives array thats why,
just `print_r($users);` below the query.

Comment: then according to array make foreach of emails in blade to make dropdown or just pass the array as an second argument if you are using blade select input.

Comment: @Rits I updated my post to include my blade code

Comment: So are you passing your data to Vue.js?

Comment: then you have to pass not an array but json string,
just return `json_encode($users)`

Answer (score 3):

if you want the email addresses from single user, try this:

```
$user = User::find(1)->email;
```

if you want the email addresses from all user/collection, try this:

```
$user = User::select('email')->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

`$users = User::all()->pluck('email');`

Comment: pluck is on collection, not collection of collection. You should use pluck in the map function.

Comment: @KrisRoofe he is not working with a collection of collections, as I understand he just wants to return the email address for all users. ```User::all()``` returns a single collection.

Comment: `all()` method will return a collection of collection.

Comment: Sorry, Here I'm not very clear. Maybe you're right. I need to test it .

Comment: @KrisRoofe If you look at the function signature for ```all``` it returns ```Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|static```.

Comment: From the laravel manual, it seems you answer is right. `pluck` and 'only` useage are not same. `collect(['product_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 100, 'discount' => false])->only(['product_id', 'name']);` and `collect([
    ['product_id' => 'prod-100', 'name' => 'Desk'],
    ['product_id' => 'prod-200', 'name' => 'Chair'],
])->pluck('name');`

Answer (score 2):

If you want all users:

`$users = User::get(['id', 'email']);`

Single user by Id:

`$user = User::find(1, ['id', 'email']);`

The above will return a collection (first case), or a single model (second case);

if want to get the email only from the result:

```
$users->pluck('email');

$user->email; // obviously :)
```

You get better performance when you limit your query to return only the columns you need which is done by passing an array to `get()` and `find` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the only on collection.

```
$emails = User::all()->map(function($user) {
    return $user->only(['email']);
});
```

Comment: This one works the best when I do a var_dump. I only get the email addresses, however this causes a problem in my dropdown in the blade template - the dropdown values (user emails) disappear

Comment: @Can you show your blade code. I don't know what you want to render in your blade php. Above code just return a array of emails.

Comment: @sorry, I've not used vue before. I cannot figure out what the js code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$users = User::first(['id','email']);
```

**OR**

```
$users = User::get(['id','email']);
```